# Sometimes, we add extra!

Tags: knowledge, cipher, visual

Make sense of this picture below. The answer is 8 letters long. Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> February

We get it by:

> Unscramble all the words inside the shapes. Take from each word the letter corresponding to the number of sides of each shape. From this we get yttrium, bromine, uranium, iron, argon. Take the symbols of each of these elements, and anagram. We get February.

More specifically:

> The unscrambled words are:
> flying, cortex, skeptic, dessert, driven, future, ligament
> arbitrary, fearless, ballon (intended to be balloon?), academy, initial, transcend, achieve
> equator, encrypt, solvable, talking, fridge, figure, pandemic
> science, boarder, tinfoil, patience
> plants, overtime, telegram, hexagon, runner
> The shapes form a pattern 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5
> Taking the corresponding letters from each word, we get
> y-t-t-r-i-u-m
> b-r-o-m-i-n-e
> u-r-a-n-i-u-e (intended to be 'm', I assume)
> i-r-o-n
> a-r-g-o-n
> The symbols of these elements are, in order, Y-Br-U-Fe-Ar.
> We can anagram this to get 'February'. This relates to the puzzle title, because we sometimes add a day to February.

Comment: Aah, didnt notice that! Anyways, well done.